# Conversion between Numeric and Double/Decimal in C#

Tags: c#, sql, decimal, numeric

I'm trying to grab elements from a certain column/Listbox which has the type "numeric" and store them in a List in C#.

```
 datTable = new DataTable();
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@
            "SELECT DISTINCT [" + form1.getColumnName() + "] 
            FROM [" + form1.getTableName() + "]", connection);
            sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
            sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);

            form1.columnStorList.DisplayMember = form1.getColumnName();
            form1.columnStorList.ValueMember = "Column1";
            form1.costStorList.DataSource = datTable;


 List<Decimal> columnElements = new List<Decimal>();

foreach (var selectedItem in form1.columnStorList.SelectedItems)
{
    DataRow row = (selectedItem as DataRowView).Row;
    columnElements.Add(row.Field<decimal>(form1.getColumnName()));
}
```

Somehow he don't want to convert it. Double doesn't work at all. For example the value `'0,000000'` gets displayed as `'0'`. I tried to convert the elements to Double but then I get `'0.0'`. Decimal should be the closest to Numeric or am I wrong? How to display it correctly?

I want to use a `SELECT` Statement `(SELECT...FROM...WHERE...=0,000000)` to search the value in the database when I highlight it in my Listbox. Since he cuts the values off that specific value won't get found in my database.

The SELECT Statement is:

```
 datTable = new DataTable();
 fullStatementColumn = Convert.ToString(columnElements[0]);
 String selectStatement = "SELECT [" + form1.colBox.Text + "] 
 FROM [" + form1.tableNameVal.Text + "] 
 WHERE convert(varchar(120),[" + form1.getColumnName() + "])='" 
 + fullStatementColumn + "'";
```

Comment: Please consider to clarify if you have issues with reading or displaying values.

Comment: "Somehow he don't want to convert it" doesn't tell us anything about what happens when you try the code you've got. What exactly happens? How exactly are you fetching the data?

Comment: Ok edited it a little bit. He displays the values correctly in my Listbox. I want them to be stored in a List. When I use decimal he just cuts it off to.

Comment: It doesn't cut it off, theres just no difference between 0 and 0.000000. Decimal has a fixed precision. You can always force to display the zeros with `string.format` or `tostring`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you issue the `SELECT` statement? If you convert the string `"0"` to a `NUMERIC` value and then match this in the database, it should work regardless of the precision of the values -- but if the value is not exactly 0, there might be a problem.

Comment: Where should I use that in the code? How can I do that when I grab the elements?

Comment: First, your `WHERE` statement is wrong. SQL uses `.` as the decimal point. Did you use string concatenation instead of passing a parameter? Second, Nothing gets cut-off. `numeric` isn't a string and `0` is equal to `0.000`. If you have issues with your query, either you use `varchar` instead of `numeric` or your `WHERE` statement is wrong.

Comment: Please post the code you use to construct the `SELECT` statement and the table schema. The statement `WHERE somefield=0,000` isn't valid SQL. It should be `WHERE somefield=0.00`

Comment: Ok therefore I try to grab the numeric value and convert it to Double. Then the Statement should be right but still he doesn't display the whole value. I post the statement